# How to checkout to another branch and forcibly overwrite changes

Tags: git

After I made some changes on `branch1` and commited them I'm trying to checkout to `branch2`:

```
>>git checkout branch2
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .gitignore
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

but I see no `.gitignore` file mentioned in updated files:

```
>>git status
On branch branch1
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch1' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
>>git stash 
No local changes to save
```

I also tried

```
>>git checkout branch2 -f
```

but got

```
error: Entry '.gitignore' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

and

```
>>git rm --cached .gitignore
```

with no success

How can I forcibly checkout to `branch2` ignoring this `"error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved as below:

```
>>git rm --cached .gitignore
>>git reset HEAD /path/to/.gitignore
```

*.gitignore appeared in No staged for commit files*

```
>>git checkout -- .gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to checkout branch2 ignoring the changes done on branch1

First reset the changes done on branch1

```
git reset --hard
```

And then checkout branch2

```
git checkout branch2
```

Hope this helps.... :)

Comment: I wanted to switch to another branch after I made commit (but not push it to remote repo) of current progress. AFAIK if I do `git reset --hard` commit will be dropped and all progress removed

Comment: I see..... which mean u need to replace branch2 with branch1 commits and changes.... is that?

Comment: Save current progress on branch1, drop `.gitignore` file and switch to branch2

Comment: Which mean when you switch to branch2, u need to have all the commits of branch1 without .gitignore file

Comment: Yeah, something like that